# taskscheduleR runs ONCE but does not run HOURLY, WEEKLY, DAILY, etc

Tags: r, r-taskscheduler

I am using taskscheduleR to run my R code. The one I have to run ONCE works just fine, however none of the other ones (HOURLY, WEEKLY, DAILY, etc.) work despite that R reports "SUCCESS: The scheduled task "test2" has successfully been created."

Here is the code I used to run ONCE (works fine):

```
library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- 'C:\\Users\\....\\File.R'
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "test1", rscript = myscript,
                     schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 
62, "%H:%M"))
```

Here is the code I used to run WEEKLY(does not work):

```
library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- 'C:\\Users\\....\\File.R'
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "test3", rscript = myscript,
                      schedule = "WEEKLY", starttime = "09:00", days = 
"THU")
```

There is no log generated in this case and it looks like task was never scheduled.

similar for the HOURLY (does not work):
library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- 'C:\Users\....\File.R'
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "test2", rscript = myscript,
schedule = "DAILY", starttime = "09:10")
There is no log generated in this case and it looks like task was never scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `startdate` argument indicating when this schedule should start working. The default of that is `startdate = format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y")`. 
So I see you posted this on February 9. That would be 09/02/2018. But note that this depends on your locale. If you are in the US and you have a default locale, that means, start from the 2nd of September instead of the 9th of February. 
If you are in Belgium, 09/02/2018 means, start on the 9th of February.

So change the startdate argument according to your locale, e.g. `startdate = format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: taskscheduler_create(taskname = "test4", rscript = myscript,
                     schedule = "HOURLY", startdate = format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y"), starttime = "10:27") - this worked well, thank you!